# DocuSign API create envelope x & y position of the tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web application where i allow user to drag and drop fields on the pdf and the pdf pages are converted to images using GhostScript so i need to fix width and height on the UI so it is accurate when i send to docusign.

Therefore with reference to docusign api create envelope where we pass signerTabs xPosition and yPosition in pixels. In order to get x & y position do we have to have pdf/image page in certain dimension i.e. 1024 x 786.

Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert PDF to Image before sending it to DocuSign API. You can have PDF fields with the proper name format as explained in [PDF to DS Tabs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor), and using DS API, DocuSign will automatically place the correct DS Tabs on the PDF Form Fields, if the fields are as per DS standards. This saves you in placing tabs using X and Y position, as X and Y position can be tricky and you might not get tab position exactly everytime where you want it to be. Converting PDF form field to DS Tabs should be preferred as you give responsibility to DocuSign to place DS tabs correctly.